# I want to change the color in a WPF ListView when column contains certain words

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textcolor

I know how to change colors if certain values match, as shown below.

How can I do for change foreground color not only same, but also values are included.

(Like `String.Contain(Value)`)

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Permission" Width="170" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding permission}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding permission}" Value="Pass">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#4c72cc"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding permission}" Value="Fail">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ef6eab"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Please explain further what you are trying to achieve !

Comment: In my sample just Changing color at completely the same  value at Pass or Fail, but I want to change color at include Value also like Pass(A)  ,  A-Pass
, D-Fail  or Fail(D) etc..

Comment: So you want to pass let's say an array of values to the `GridViewColumn`, and change the color when there is some hits?

Comment: No. Include "Pass"(Not only equal) column's value change foreground color

Comment: Use either two value converters or a single multivalueConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that there are two ways:

**Method 1**

Either define two converters that check whether your string contains the "Pass"/"Fail" values:

```
public class PassConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string)?.Contains("Pass");            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class FailConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string)?.Contains("Fail");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add the converters to your static resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <YourNameSpace:PassConverter x:Key="PassConverter"></local:PassConverter>
    <YourNameSpace:FailConverter x:Key="FailConverter"></local:FailConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

And update your Triggers to use them:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Permission" Width="170" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Permission}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=permission, Converter={StaticResource PassConverter}}">
                                                <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#4c72cc"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding permission,Converter={StaticResource FailConverter}}" >
                                                <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ef6eab"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

**Method 2**

You could also use a single `MultiValueConverter` and pass either "Pass" or "Fail" strings with the `permission` value and check like so:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Permission" Width="170" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Permission}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassFailConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="permission"/>
                                                        <Binding>
                                                            <Binding.Source>
                                                                <system:String>
                                                                    Pass
                                                                </system:String>
                                                            </Binding.Source>
                                                        </Binding>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#4c72cc"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassFailConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="permission"/>
                                                        <Binding>
                                                            <Binding.Source>
                                                                <system:String>
                                                                    Fail
                                                                </system:String>
                                                            </Binding.Source>
                                                        </Binding>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ef6eab"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

And the `multivalueconverter` should look something like that:

```
 public class PassFailConverter:IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (values[0] as string).Contains(values[1] as string);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include the converter in your static resources:

```
<YourNameSpace:PassFailConverter x:Key="PassFailConverter"></local:PassFailConverter>
```

Comment: Thank you. This method was very useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value converter for that (IValueConverter) and binding color directly to "permission" and convert to color

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.